# Odoo mail.activity creation

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

I'm trying to create a custom activity using `'mail.activity'` model, with custom values, and show me this error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/mail/models/mail_activity.py", line 108, in 
_compute_res_name
activity.res_name = self.env[activity.res_model].browse(activity.res_id).name_get()[0][1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I think is because in the core `mail.activity` model, the access to the `0` and `1` position in the array crash my program, but I dont know why.

Here is my code for the activity creation:

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals)
    user_id = self.user_id
    date_deadline = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=7)

    data = {
        'res_id': self.id,
        'res_model_id': self.env['ir.model'].search([('model', '=', 'hr.applicant')]).id,
        'user_id': user_id.id,
        'summary': 'foo bar',
        'activity_type_id': self.env.ref('custom.activity_applicant').id,
        'date_deadline': date_deadline
        }
    self.env['mail.activity'].create(data)
    return super().create(vals)
```

There is something in the field `res_id` that I don't know about or something else.

Comment: Where are you creating this record, check the self.id what is its value exactly

Comment: Make sure that this function is called from he.applicant model only so self.id will be applicant's id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already figured out what was wrong, I was calling `self.id` before even creating the object, and `id` is a null value then. I change the object creation before this part of the code and it works fine.

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals)
    new = super().create(vals)
    user_id = new.user_id
    date_deadline = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=7)

    data = {
        'res_id': new.id,
        'res_model_id': self.env['ir.model'].search([('model', '=', 'hr.applicant')]).id,
        'user_id': user_id.id,
        'summary': 'foo bar',
        'activity_type_id': self.env.ref('custom.activity_applicant').id,
        'date_deadline': date_deadline
        }
    self.env['mail.activity'].create(data)
    return new
```

Answer (score 0):

You got that error because Odoo expects a list of pairs `(id, text_repr)` for each record and it found probably an empty list (the returned result will be used to build dictionaries directly from sequences of key-value pairs to prepare the display names).

Make sure the returned result by the hr applicant's `name_get` method is a list of pairs.

```
@api.multi
def name_get(self):
    result = []
    res = super(HrApplicant, self).name_get()
    # the result list should be filled with pairs
    return result
```

Comment: Does this answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Not for the creation but for approvals.

```
    def action_apply_quotation_validate(self):
    product_manager = self.product_manager
    self.state = 'to_approve'
    date = datetime.date.today()
    data = {
        'res_id': self.id,
        'res_model_id': self.env['ir.model'].search([('model', '=', 'sale.order')]).id,
        'user_id': product_manager.id,
        'summary': 'Quotation Validate',
        'activity_type_id': self.env.ref('connex_phase_01.mail_act_so_validate').id,
        'date_deadline': date,
        'note': 'Please validate the Quotation'
    }
    self.env['mail.activity'].create(data)
```